# How to add a database in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, mdf

I have been sent a database called StudentsDB.mdf and I want to enter it into my SQL Server Management Studio databases . How to do that ?

I want to know if I copy a .mdf file from the directory where are all my databases which is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA
and sent it to another person will he be able to import this database in his SQL Server Management Studio and see the database?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx

Comment: Short answer is, "yes".

Comment: If you want to send a database, you're better of sending a database BACKUP, not the actual MDF file

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

Step 1
Right-click “Databases” and click the “Attach” option to open the Attach Databases dialog box.

Step 2
Click the “Add” button to open the Locate Database Files dialog box.

Step 3
Type in the full name of the .MDF file, including the full device and directory path, as the following example illustrates:
c:\StudentsDB.mdf
Click the "OK" button. SQL Server Management Studio loads the database from the .MDF file.

OR

Step 1
Click “New Query” in the Management Studio’s main toolbar.

Step 2
Type a Create Database statement using the following Transact-SQL code:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON 
(FILENAME = 'c:\StudentsDB.mdf'), 
(FILENAME = ' c:\StudentsDB.ldf') FOR ATTACH;
```

Step 3
Click the “Execute” button in the Transact-SQL toolbar. SQL Server Management Studio restores the database.

OR

```
CREATE DATABASE StudentDB ON
(FILENAME = N'C:\StudentsDB.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO
```

Comment: TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

An error occurred when attaching the database(s).  Click the hyperlink in the Message column for details.

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------

Comment: This will not work as this is a single mdf file without the log file. You will need to do what I have showing in my answer, use the system proc to deal with this specific situation.

Comment: @M.Ali:- This is specifc situation thats why I am included some options to user which may be help to OP

Comment: For those who get the error "An error occured when attaching the database(s). Click the hyperlink in the Message column for details." (with no hyperlink). Try restarting the Management Studio as Administrator.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid this should be an answer rather than a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Execute the following command from SSMS.

```
USE master;
GO

EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname   = N'StudentsDB'
                             ,@physname = N'D:\<path to mdf file>\StudentsDB.mdf'
GO
```

Now if you refresh the database list in SSMS it should show a database `StudentsDB` in the list.

Comment: Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 1
Unable to open the physical file "D:\StudentsDB.mdf". Operating system error 5

Comment: That was just a demo path, you should provide the actual path where ever that .mdf file is located. Error clearer suggests that there is no file on that location, or if the location path does exist then just make sure user has read/write permissions to that file.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if I copy a *.mdf file ... and [send] it to another person, will he be able to import this database?

You can do this, but there are a few considerations. The first is that you need to take the database offline, or use another command to ensure there are no pending transactions waiting to be written or locks or latches waiting to be closed.

The second consideration is that, once the database is imported, you may need to recreate (by hand or by script) a few items that aren't stored within the mdf file itself. This includes users and permissions, links to other databases, and other services that are provided by at the Server level rather than the Database level.